# Create variables no matter the nr of rows of the data in clipboard

Tags: python

I created a program that does certain operations in a web based software (with Selenium) using the data that i have in windows Clipboard (it's rows with string like QWERTY123 ). It means that for each row the program copy from clip board that row, paste in a field and execute a task. This task should be performed the same way for all rows. My problem is that same times the clipboard has 2 rows (like the code below), other times for examplehas 20, other 77...a so on. How could I modify my code to work no matter the number of rows I have?

Please see what I have done here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

import tkinter as tk


path_to_Ie = 'C:\\Python34\\ChromeDriver\\ChromeDriver.exe' 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_Ie)
url = 'https://wwww.corp/'
browser.get(url)


browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='username']").send_keys("user")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='password']").send_keys("pass")

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='login-link']").click()

browser.get('https://wwww.corp/soft.html')

time.sleep(2)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-column']/div[4]/form/div[1]/span/label").click()

time.sleep(2)


browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='agent_list_filter_id_2']").clear()

root = tk.Tk()
# keep the window from showing
root.withdraw()

# read the clipboard
machineName = root.clipboard_get()


one1, two2 = machineName.split('\n') # generates variables for the data (2 rows) of clipboard


one = one1.replace(" ", "") #
two = two2.replace(" ", "") #

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='agent_list_filter_id_2']").send_keys(one) # send first row data



browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-column']/div[4]/form/div[1]/span/span[1]").click()



browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-select-all']/span/span").click()



browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-delete']/span/span").click()


browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='btn_save']").click() # last command to delete the first row


browser.get('https://wwww.corp/soft.html')

time.sleep(2)


browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='agent_list_filter_id_2']").clear()

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='agent_list_filter_id_2']").send_keys(two) # send 2nd row data



browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-column']/div[4]/form/div[1]/span/span[1]").click()



browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-select-all']/span/span").click()



browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-delete']/span/span").click()


browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='btn_save']").click() # last command to delete the 2nd row
```

Any input is welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to assign each clipboard row to a variable - using `split('\n')` gives you a *list* with each row from the clipboard an item in that list. Using the list you can access each row by subscript, i.e. the position of the item in the list.

Also, you seem to want to remove all spaces from each clipboard row? I'm not sure whether this is what you intend: `'Hi there you'` => `'Hithereyou'`. You can do that in one go on the clipboard data before splitting it:

```
rows = root.clipboard_get().replace(' ', '').split('\n')
```

Or if you want to remove leading and trailing whitespace from each row *after* it has been split into rows:

```
rows = root.clipboard_get().split('\n')
rows = [row.strip() for row in rows]    # removes leading and trailing whitespace from each row
print(rows)
print(rows[0])    # the first row
print(rows[1])    # the second row
```

Assuming the latter, if the clipboard contained e.g. (note the leading whitespace)

```
    Some data from the first row
  More data on the second row
```

The output would be:

```
['Some data from the first row', 'More data on the second row']
Some data from the first row
More data on the second row
```

So that covers the basics. Now, looking at the structure of your code, you do essentially the same thing for each clipboard row. That means that you can use a loop to iterate over each row and perform the required browser commands:

```
rows = root.clipboard_get().split('\n')
rows = [row.strip() for row in rows]

for row in rows:
    browser.get('https://wwww.corp/soft.html')
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='agent_list_filter_id_2']").clear()

    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='agent_list_filter_id_2']").send_keys(row)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-column']/div[4]/form/div[1]/span/span[1]").click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-select-all']/span/span").click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-delete']/span/span").click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='btn_save']").click()
```